# Move Panel when pn.Scroll() is fired

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I have a panel `MainPanel` that contains 2 panels `pnContRoles` (scrolls horizontally) and `pnContOperations` (scrolls vertically). Each have different size and location. I have another panel `pnIntersection` that I put in `pnContOperations` as default. I want to change `pnIntersection` from `pnContOperations` to `pnContRoles`. This have to come with a change of size and location of `pnIntersection`. All of this is, to be able, when scrolling `pnContRoles` or `pnContOperations`, to move `pnIntersection` accordingly. In every panel the controls are textboxes(if that matters).

```
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        TextBox tbCopy = new TextBox();
        ToolTip TTL = new ToolTip();
        String TooltipL;

        tb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        tb.Name = idRoleL + idOperationL.ToString();
        tb.Text = valeurL;
        tb.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        tb.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None; //pour enlever les scrollbars dans tout les textboxes
        tb.HideSelection = true;//pour ne pas avoir le focus dans le precedent textbox
        tb.Size = new Size(100, 20);
        tb.Location = new Point((posRoleL - 1) * 140 + 20 + 2, (posOperationL - 1) * 40 + 10 + 2);
        tb.Visible = true;
        tb.Cursor = Cursors.IBeam;
        tb.WordWrap = false;

        tbCopy.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        tbCopy.Name = tb.Name;
        tbCopy.Text = tb.Text;
        tbCopy.TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        tbCopy.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.None; //pour enlever les scrollbars dans tout les textboxes
        tbCopy.HideSelection = true;//pour ne pas avoir le focus dans le precedent textbox
        tbCopy.Size = new Size(100, 20);
        tbCopy.Location = tb.Location;
        tbCopy.Visible = true;
        tbCopy.Cursor = Cursors.IBeam;
        tbCopy.WordWrap = false;

        TooltipL = "Veuillez écrire des numéros decimals positifs, merci.";            
        TTL.SetToolTip(tb, TooltipL);

        #endregion

        #region EVENEMENTS TEXTBOX
        //Evenement quand le text change(si le texte quand écrit ce sont des numéros positif)            
        tb.Leave += (senderL, eL) =>
        {
            string patron = @"^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*$";
            string input = tb.Text;
            Match m = Regex.Match(input, patron);

            if (m.Success)
            {
                EventControlAddin(5, (string)idOperationL.ToString().PadRight(10) + ";" + idRoleL.PadRight(10) + ";" + (string)tb.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Vous devez écrire un numéro valide et decimal positif, s'il vous plaît.");
                tb.Text = "???";
                tb.BackColor = Color.IndianRed;
                tb.Focus();
            }

        };

        #endregion            

        pnContRoles.Scroll += (senderL, eL) =>
        {                
            pnContRoles.BringToFront();               
        };
        pnContOperations.Scroll += (senderL, eL) =>
        {   
            pnContOperations.BringToFront();
        };            

        #region AJOUTS

        pnIntersectRoles.Location = new Point(0, 40);
        pnIntersectRoles.Size = new Size(nRolesG * 140, 320);
        pnIntersectRoles.Parent = pnContRoles;

        pnIntersectRoles.Controls.Add(tbCopy);
        pnContRoles.Controls.Add(pnIntersectRoles);
        MainPanel.Controls.Add(pnContRoles); 

        pnIntersectOperations.Location = new Point(220, 0);
        pnIntersectOperations.Size = new Size(840, (nOperationsG + nPhasesG) * 40);
        pnIntersectOperations.Parent = pnContOperations;

        pnIntersectOperations.Controls.Add(tb);
        pnContOperations.Controls.Add(pnIntersectOperations);
        MainPanel.Controls.Add(pnContOperations);
```

Comment: Remove first, then add to the other Panel.  It can't have two Parents.

Comment: I edited my question. @DonBoitnott, thanks,  I removed from pnContOperations and add it to pnContRoles but it is not working. The location and the size are not good. And if i change the size and the location of the pnIntersection, it dissapears. Maybe i have to remove the textboxes inside it too, and then add everything...

Comment: Does it need to be moved?  What about two of the same setup, and hide/show them as needed?  Re-parenting controls is clunky at best.

Comment: i am going to do two pnIntersection différents in size, location and parent. I am going to remove textboxes from one and add to the other, as needed. I will post later the possible solution...Could this work?

Comment: It is not working, at the moment. I edited the code. The textboxes that will get generate in the pnIntersectRoles and pnIntersectOperations are the same. Maybe i need to have duplicate also?

Comment: Hi, i found the solution, i edited my code above to show. I did it with 2 séparâtes pnIntersectRoles and pnIntersectOperations and 2 textboxes, tb and tbCopy. I just need, for my problem, to do the same when dragging. And update the textboxes text, and locations. Yeah, i am happy now. Not letting me answer the question is no nice. Have a nice day you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution, i edited my code above to show. I did it with 2 séparâtes pnIntersectRoles and pnIntersectOperations and 2 textboxes, tb and tbCopy. I just need, for my problem, to do the same when dragging. And update the textboxes text, and locations. Yeah, i am happy now